# Where do BH dissipate heat that aquire from infalling stars or matter from their accretion disks?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, temperature, dissipation

Where do BH dissipate heat that aquire from infalling stars or matter from their accretion disks? Is BH temperature increasing due to that events?

Answer (score 1):

Stellar-sized black holes don't emit or dissipate (almost) anything$^1$.

Some of the heat of infalling matter (which gets hot as it is funnelled towards the black hole) is radiated by that infalling matter. The rest simply ends up increasing the mass of the black hole; it is not dissipated.

Classical black holes do not have a temperature. But a quantum-mechanical treatment suggests stellar-sizes black holes might have a very low temperature, close to absolute zero, that decreases as their mass increases.

$^1$ There is a theoretical prediction of "Hawking radiation" that is totally negligible for a stellar-sized black hole.

Comment: A well phrased answer, correct, concise, clear, and without misconceptions +1

Answer (score 1):

A convenient definition of temperature is using black body radiation. That is if we have a black body we can define its temperature by measuring the radiation it emits and then use the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law), [Wien's displacement law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law) or [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) to relate this to a temperature. The advantage of this is that it is a universal method of measuring temperature that applies to each and every black body regardless of how the black bode was formed.

For objects that are not black bodies we can (conceptually at least) place them in thermal contact with a black body so both equilibrate to the same temperature, then measure the temperature of the black body. Though in practice most objects are close enough to black bodies that Planck's law still works.

Anyhow, when we try to apply this to a classical black body we run into an unexpected problem. Nothing can escape from a black hole event horizon, and that includes black body radiation, so a classical black hole cannot radiate. Using the above laws then tells us that the temperature of all black holes is absolute zero. That is, no matter what you throw into a black hole you cannot heat it up. The thermal energy in the objects you throw in just increases the black hole mass.

As you point out in your question it is important to differentiate between the black hole and the accretion disk surrounding it. The accretion disk is outside the event horizon and it does indeed get hot and radiate just like all other forms of matter. But this is the temperature of the accretion disk not the temperature of the black hole.

Finally, we find that once we include quantum effects it turns out that black holes do radiate and therefore do have a temperature. This is called [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) after its discoverer Stephen Hawking. However for stellar mass black holes this radiation is very, very weak and the associated temperature is so close to absolute zero that it could not ever be measured. The temperature of a black hole with the mass of the Sun would be 0.00000006 Kelvin.

Comment: “*Nothing can escape from a black hole event horizon, and that includes black body radiation*” - In coordinates of an external observer, nothing ever crosses the horizon. The matter of the collapsed stars is still outside and conceptually can radiate. The reason for the lack of radiation is not the horizon, but the redshift.

Comment: Ah, safesphere, where would we be without your always entertaining comments on anything relating to general relativity?

Comment: In a happy oblivion of misconceptions? :)